# keyError when moving file to another directory

Tags: python, pandas, shutil

Lets say you have the following df:

```
dfresult_secondlook = {'relfilepath': ['test.pdf', 'epic.pdf' ], 'col2': [3, 4]}
```

I want to move a file that is in this df to another folder with the following code:

```
#moving files from secondlook df to secondlook folder

sourceDir = 'C:\\Users\\Max12\\Desktop\\xml\\pdfminer\\UiPath\\attachments\\75090058\\Status\\PDFsend'
destDir = 'C:\\Users\\Max12\\Desktop\\xml\\pdfminer\\UiPath\\attachments\\75090058\\Status\\SecondLook'

files = os.listdir(sourceDir)
filesToMove = dfresult_secondlook

def move(file, sourceDir, destDir):
    sourceFile = os.path.join(sourceDir, file)
    if not os.path.exists(destDir):
        os.makedirs(destDir)
    try:
        shutil.move(sourceFile, destDir)
    except:
        pass

for i in range(len(filesToMove)):
    file = filesToMove['relfilepath'][i]
    move(file,sourceDir,destDir)
    
#writing files to excel for further examination
book = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\secondlook.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\secondlook.xlsx", engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

dfresult_secondlook.to_excel(writer, "Main", header = False, index = False, startrow = writer.sheets['Main'].max_row)

writer.save()
```

However, I'm getting a KeyError:

```
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4043ec85df9c> in <module>
     17 
     18 for i in range(len(filesToMove)):
---> 19     file = filesToMove['relfilepath'][i]
     20     move(file,sourceDir,destDir)
     21
```

I don't see what's going wrong after 2 hours..

Please help!

Comment: Hi @Max, can you check whether 'relfilepath' key does exist in your dfresult_secondlook, it might be better if you can give a sample data of dfresult_secondlook,

Comment: Yes it does exist! I will provide some sample data

Comment: {'line amount#1': {4: '5.0'},
 'line amount#2': {4: '15.0'},
 'line amount#3': {4: '5.0'},
 'BTW': {4: '0.55'},
 'filepath': {4: 'C:\\Users\\Max12\\Desktop\\xml\\pdfminer\\UiPath\\attachments\\75090058\\Status\\PDFsend\\221311625.pdf'},
 'relfilepath': {4: '221311625.pdf'}}

Comment: yeah first iteration fails because zero key doesn't exist in relfilepath
you can just get the relfilepath directly without using loop
file = filesToMove['relfilepath'][4]
move(file,sourceDir,destDir)

Answer (score 1):

According to the sample data you provided, `relfilepath` is a dict which does not always have 0 as a key. Thus, your for / loop, starting from 0, fails.
You could then try this:

```py
for i in range(len(filesToMove)):
    try:
        file = filesToMove['relfilepath'][i]
        move(file,sourceDir,destDir)
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

PS: you should modify the beginning of your post, where `dfresult_secondlook` shows 'relfilepath' as a list instead of a dict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the code says "continue not properly in loop".. What would you do?

Comment: SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: Sorry, I meant to encapsulate inside the for / loop, not outside of it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Laurent. However it did not move the file because the index of the file in the df is 4. Is there a possibility to reindex the df starting from 0? I've tried to search online however did not find the right answer

Comment: I've found it! 
dfresult_secondlook = dfresult_secondlook.reset_index

Comment: then the for loop starts from 0